# Japanese characters in JavaFX app is not antialiased

Tags: javafx, fonts

I have a small JavaFX app for learning japanese words. The problem is that japanese characters in the TableView are not antialiased. All other text is OK. (Please note that images inserted to Stack Overflos are automatically scaled and thus little bit smoothed. It's even worse in reality)
[image]

Here you can see it scaled, you can see it little bit better.
[image]

I remade the app in WPF and there's no such problem, all fonts are equaly smoothed.

[image]
Do you have an idea what do I need to do in JavaFX to achieve smoothness of japanese font as well?

Comment: Please create an [mcve], a simple minimal example that somebody else could run on their pc to replicate, it just needs to show one or two Japanese words, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following methods?

css：

```
.text{
-fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;
}
```

start option:
-Dprism.lcdtext=false

System property:

```
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false”);
```

Comment: May I ask, how you added a Japanese font to your application? I use the default font, and some glyph are showing correctly, some not.